# How to use a remote web page as web background?

Tags: background-image

How to make web background with a remote web page https://map.norsecorp.com/?

Comment: You mean like linking an external webpage to your own? You could only use an <iframe> tag for that.

Comment: yes iframe i did. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And at last I foud this code

```
    <div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%; cell-spacing: 0; padding: 0; marign: 0; border: 0; inline: false; outline: false;">
      <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
        src="https://map.norsecorp.com/">
      </iframe>
    </div>
```